# how to add a full screen custom camera view on Buttons over there eg:snapchat

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEuH3.png

I want the same layout like this the full screen camera and buttons placed over there like snapchat View.

Comment: Show what you've done, if you researched something. You cant ask people to do the work from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by something following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Click"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Here surface view will act as camera preview screen .if you want to add more views on screen you can add below surface view and those views will appear on screen over the camera